# ASP.NET. Странная ошибка при обработке _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Сидел правил `css`, попутно проверяя изменения на сайте, развернутом в IIS.

В какой-то момент при обновлении страницы получаю ошибку ниже:

```
Ошибка сервера в приложении '/'.
Не удалось обработать следующий файл, так как его расширение ".cshtml" может не поддерживаться: "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml".

Описание: Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего веб-запроса. Изучите трассировку стека для получения дополнительных сведений о данной ошибке и о вызвавшем ее фрагменте кода. 

Сведения об исключении: System.Web.HttpException: Не удалось обработать следующий файл, так как его расширение ".cshtml" может не поддерживаться: "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml".

Ошибка источника: Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего веб-запроса. Информацию о происхождении и месте возникновения исключения можно получить, используя следующую трассировку стека исключений.

Трассировка стека: 

[HttpException (0x80004005): Не удалось обработать следующий файл, так как его расширение ".cshtml" может не поддерживаться: "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml".]
   System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerExceptionUtil.ThrowIfUnsupportedExtension(String virtualPath, HttpException e) +297488
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.CreatePageFromVirtualPath(String virtualPath, HttpContextBase httpContext, Func`2 virtualPathExists, DisplayModeProvider displayModeProvider, IDisplayMode displayMode) +369
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) +258
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +122
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +88
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +371
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +375
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +31
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +437
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +399
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +157

Информация о версии: Платформа Microsoft .NET Framework, версия:4.0.30319; ASP.NET, версия:4.6.1586.0
```

Откуда она взялась я вообще не могу понять, т.к. менял я только `css`. И мне абсолютно не понятно как её исправить, в гугле не нашел

Comment: Попробуйте кэш asp.net почтистить - удалить все из C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ и C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ - и перезапустить iis

Comment: @PashaPash помогло, спасибо, вынесите коммент в ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по ошибке, побился кэш ASP.NET. Нужно почистить его и перезапустить IIS:

Powershell, as admin:

```
net stop w3svc
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\*" -Force -Recurse
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\*" -Force -Recurse
net start w3svc
```

Comment: подскажи в чем причина этой ошибки, частенько стала появляться...